# Spring boot how to get resource method in request filter

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am building a REST API with Spring Boot, and now trying to create a custom filter class where I need to access the resource method that would be invoked by the request. I need that in order to check if the method is annotated with a certain annotation, e.g.

```
@Component
@ApplicationScope
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Method method = // get the target method somehow
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
            // business logic here
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

With RESTEasy I would do something like this

```
@Context
private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;
```

where ResourceInfo has methods to get the resource class and method that is the target of the request. Is there a similar class in Spring Boot that would do the same job?

Comment: Not with a filter. You can use a `HandlerInterceptor` but what you really want (at least looks like it) is plain AOP.

Comment: I see, too bad it's not possible with a filter. I took a look at the spring aop library, which might be helpful in my case (though I went with another solution where I don't need to check annotations in the filter class).